# Writing to file across activities in append mode in android

Tags: android

i have  an application which has some set of actvities say 5.

But now i want to write to common file among all activities .**Does the data written to file in one activity shall reflect in the other activity so that offset of the file is shared**?

i have a problem here i may need to switch between activities many times,so an activity may gets instantiated and destroyed so many times. so if i open the same file again and again in oninit method of each activity is that going to create problem for me.

please tell me some effective ways to accomplish this task.

Comment: Yup!..File will reside at a particular location,and if you are reading the same file in append mode, it should work!!..